# Patterns for caching/storing aggregations in Mongo documents (Ruby, mongoid)?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, design-patterns, mongoid

I'm collecting tweets across a set of accounts and want to do such calculations as tweets per (given) month, or average tweet length per tweet in a given month.

Once this calculation is done once for a time in the past (e.g. user X tweet 4.2 times/day in May 2010), it's not one that needs to be recalculated (a mass deletion of past tweets is an edge case)...so given that condition, what's the basic pattern for executing this aggregation upon demand and then memoizing it within the Mongo document.

example:

```
t = TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name=>'Bob')
puts t.tweet_rate(:month=>5, :year=>2010)
# ...

puts t.tweet_rate(:month=>5, :year=>2010)
# cached/memoized result is stored inside document
```

I can guess at ways to write my own class that handles this but I figured this was a common enough pattern in the NoSQL world (I'm just starting out with MongoDB) where new attributes can be tacked on at will.

(I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Mongoid as my ORM, but don't think that matters conceptually)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, memoizing in the DB is a common pattern.  With MongoDB, you can use the richness of BSON to store an embedded array so that you can easily and efficiently fetch the data with one DB request.

There are some nuances with embedded document arrays in MongoDB.  The following test shows usage for the '$elemMatch' Query Selector for Arrays and for the '$' Update Array operator.  It also has examples for both client-side and server-side update.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/

While your monthly update is infrequent, you can preallocate to avoid the overhead forced by growing a document.  Preallocation requires a few extra lines of code, and you'll have to handle the year epoch as well.

Ruby 1.9.3, Mongoid 3.0.15, Moped 1.3.1

```
class TwitterAccount
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :screen_name, type: String
  embeds_many :tweet_rates
end

class TweetRate
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :year, type: Integer
  field :month, type: Integer
  field :rate, type: Float
  embedded_in :twitter_account
end
```

test/unit/tweet_rate_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class TweetRateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    TwitterAccount.delete_all
    TwitterAccount.create(:screen_name => 'Bob')
  end

  test "monthly append" do
    t = TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name => 'Bob')
    assert_equal('Bob', t.screen_name)
    t.tweet_rates.create(:year => 2010, :month =>5, :rate => 12.3)
    t.save!
    tr = TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name => 'Bob').tweet_rates
    assert_equal(1, tr.size)
  end

  test "prealloc for a year" do
    t = TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name => 'Bob')
    assert_equal('Bob', t.screen_name)

    # prealloc for a whole year
    year = 2012
    (1..12).each do |month|
      t.tweet_rates.create(:year => year, :month => month, :rate => -1.0)
    end
    t.save!
    t = TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name => 'Bob')
    assert_equal(12, t.tweet_rates.size)

    # update a rate using client-side Ruby
    month, rate  = 10, 12.3
    t.tweet_rates.detect{|tr| tr.year == year && tr.month == month}.rate = rate
    t.save!
    assert_equal(rate, TwitterAccount.find_by(:screen_name => 'Bob')
                                     .tweet_rates.detect{|tr| tr.year == year && tr.month == month}.rate) # used #detect NOT overloaded #find

    # update a rate using MongoDB server-side
    month, rate = 11, 4.56
    TwitterAccount.where({ :screen_name => 'Bob',
                           :tweet_rates => { '$elemMatch' => { :year => year, :month => 11 } } })
                  .update('$set' => { 'tweet_rates.$.rate' => rate })
    assert_equal(rate, TwitterAccount.where({ :screen_name => 'Bob'}).first
                                     .tweet_rates.detect{|tr| tr.year == year && tr.month == month}.rate) # use #detect and NOT overloaded #find
  end
end
```

Hope that this helps.